# Fluentd Regex: Group multiple values in single group

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, fluentd

I am trying to snip out a field from the following string:

`|null|23|2017-07-11T19:03:40.511|Test|PageUnque#MasterCache|123450000||`

After parsing the string, the result should be like:

`type: null
id: 23
message: 2017-07-11T19:03:40.511|Test|PageUnque#MasterCache
code: 123450000`

I tried using the below Regex, but it didn't worked as expected.

`^\|(?<type>.*?)\|(?<id>.*?)\|(?<message>.[^\#]*)\|(?<code>.*?)\|$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if there were some more examples or more specifics about the information expected to be in each field.  The main problem I saw with your regex was that it appeared you wanted to capture "2017-07-11T19:03:40.511|Test|PageUnque#MasterCache", but you disallowed the '#' character in the message capture group

```
(?<message>.[^\#]*)
```

Instead this is what I did.  I'll note that I assumed that the code is going to consist of only digits. https://regex101.com/r/urC2rj/1

```
^\|(?<type>.*?)\|(?<id>.*?)\|(?<message>.*)\|(?<code>[0-9]+)\|\|$
```

I didn't change this in the regexes but using ".*?" could be a bit risky as it allows your regex to capture a lot of things.  Depending on your data, it may or may not be important.

Comment: Great!! it worked like a charm. Thanks for your prompt response.